# Flash message is not display on handlerbar template using node js with passport js

Tags: node.js, connect-flash

I am trying to show message in handlebar template using connect-flash package but message is not showing and its print count when i use {{loginMessage}} in login page. but not display message.
 here is my code

file..routes/index.js

```
 var express =  require('express');
 var router =   express.Router();
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var flash =    require('connect-flash');
 const m_db =   require('.././config/mongo_connection');
 var Site =     require('.././models/site');
 var User = require('../models/user');
 var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
 var passport = require('passport');
 var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
 require('.././config/passport')(passport);
 //routes start here
 router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {    
 res.render('passports/login.hbs', { message:   req.flash('loginMessage','failed login') });
```

})

my app.js

```
  app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
  app.use(flash());
 //
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 // passport config

 app.use(logger('dev'));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(cookieParser());
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 app.use('/', index);
 app.use('/users', users);
 app.use('/api', api);

 // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
 });

 // error handler
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
 });
  module.exports = app;
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {           

  res.render('passports/login.hbs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); 
     .
     .
```

What I want to say it:

```
req.flash('loginMessage','failed login')
```

is for setting the flash variable name `loginMessage` to `failed login`

```
req.flash('loginMessage')
```

and this is when your read the flash that your set later on. The code above return array of flash messages(if more than one flash are set) of `loginMessage`.

Comment: Thanks for reply
My message configuration is in passport js.. when print {{loginMessage}} it  is not display any error but my errors is set in  
file: passport.js
if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));
                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password.'));
                return done(null, user);

Comment: How can i check flash message in handlebar template.?

Comment: Have you tried `message: req.flash('loginMessage')` instead of `message:  req.flash('loginMessage','failed login')` when rendering template?

Comment: yes I have tried this 
 res.render('passports/login.hbs');
  req.flash('loginMessage')

Comment: same issue here..can Icheck all list of flash message in hbs or routes file?

Comment: Could I see how you render them in `.hbs` file?

Comment: yes 
`  {{messages}}
        {{message}}
        {{loginMessage}}` but not display any any one message

Comment: Could you edit and add `.hbs` file as well as `post` request, I want to see how you redirect after login.

Comment: login.hbs
  <!-- Account FORM -->
        {{messages}}
        {{message}}
        {{loginMessage}}
        {{#if message}}

                <div class="notice error">
                    <i class="icon-remove-sign icon-large"></i>
                    {{{message}}}
                    <a href="#close" class="icon-remove"></a>
                </div>

        {{/if}}

Comment: this is post route: 

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true,
}));

Comment: I am using passport js

Comment: https://www.danielgynn.com/build-an-authentication-app-using-express-node-passport/ 
I am follow this tuts but this in ejs but code in handlebar js.

Comment: Are you using [expess-handlebar](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) module.

Comment: I have create project using this command with hbs package
"express --hbs node_passport"

Comment: Without express-handlebars module you have to hard code compile template [](http://handlebarsjs.com/). I suggest you go with express handlebars. Follow (https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) for the setup.

Comment: Thanks i try to this.

Comment: I have done something similar using passportjs and express-handlebar before. [check out](https://github.com/NERDYLIZARD/shopping-cart) if you want something to compare.